# Why is the largest power of prime $p$ that divides $n$ called the "order" of $n$ at $p$?

Tags: soft-question, terminology

Largest exponent $a$ of the power $p^a$ of prime $p$ that divides $n$ is called *order* of $n$ at $p$ and denoted $ord_p (n)$.

> Why is this function called *order*?

Would it be better to call it *occurence* of $p$ in $n$?

Comment: It is also  very commonly called the $p$-valuation of $n$. This being said I suppose I suppose it is by analogy with the Taylor's expansion of a $\mathcal C^\infty$ function, where this order expresses, precisely, the order of multiplicity of a zero of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Order functions $o\colon R\rightarrow \mathbb{N}_0$ from a ring $R$ to non-negative integers in general satisfy $o(xy)=o(x)+o(y)$ and $o(x+y)\ge \min\{o(x),o(y)\}$. Since $o(n)=ord_p(n)$ satisfies this properties, it makes 
sense to call it order function.

Another example: Order functions on the universal enveloping algebra $R=U(\mathfrak{g})$ of a Lie algebra, via Poincare-Birkhoff-Witt basis.